# Number of ways of selecting $n$ numbers from a set to form different sum

Tags: combinatorics

The exact question is:

> If $10$ numbers are chosen randomly out of first $100$ odd numbers and $A$ is the sum of those $10$ numbers then how many different values of $A$ are possible?

Comment: @David there are no restrictions on the value of A.

Comment: Instead of working with odd summands, write each odd summand $y$ as $y=2x-1$, where $x$ is an arbitrary integer between $1$ and $50\;$inclusive. With that conversion, the question becomes: How many numbers can be expressed as a sum of $10\;$integers between $1$ and $50\;$inclusive? Then instead of $10$ summands, consider $n$ summands. Analyze small values of $n$, say $n=1,2,3$. A clear pattern will be evident. Induction will work to prove that what appears to hold actually holds.

Comment: Where you write "randomly", I think you mean "arbitrarily". The rest of the post never refers to the random distribution of the numbers.